# why my command not showing up the popup with a input field?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I m using chrome.commands API and trying to build a extension which shows a input box popup in which I can enter search query and press enter and it will search it on google for me in new tab.

But the problem is even when I press given command i.e. Alt+5 in this case it does not show anything.

This is my first time trying to make chrome extension so maybe I@m missing something.

Below is the code:

logic.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    if(command == toggle){
        d = document;
          var f = d.createElement('form');
          f.action = '';
          f.method = 'get';
          var i = d.createElement('input');
          i.id = 'bar';
          i.type = 'text';
          i.name = 'search';
          f.appendChild(i);
          d.body.appendChild(f);

        document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
            var query = document.getElementById("bar").value;
            var gString = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=";
            var newUrl = gString + query;

            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                chrome.tabs.create({url: newUrl});
            }

        },false);
    }

});
```

manifesto.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name" : "shortcut google",
"description": "press keys shift+g for a instant google search",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "search.html"
},

"commands":
{
    "toggle" : 
    {
        "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Alt+5",
            "mac": "Command+Shift+5"
        },
        "description" : "toggle the search bar.",
        "global": true
    }
},

"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
}
```

search.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>google search</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the extension architecture overview: the background page is a hidden separate page. Only content scripts can modify the page contents. You need to inject one with chrome.tabs.executeScript or declare one in manifest and use messaging from the background page to the content script to make it display the toolbar.

Comment: You need a background page, not just a popup. Your popup (code and page) does not exist unless the popup is actually currently being shown. Thus, there is no listener in existence for the `commands.onCommand` event unless you can see your popup.